# PyQt no jpeg support

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, jpeg

I don't have `jpg` support in my Qt installation in python. How can I install additional libraries for `JPG` support?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()

Out[5]: 
[PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('bmp'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('pbm'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('pgm'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('png'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('ppm'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('xbm'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('xpm')]
```

Comment: The solution in these links doesn't help unfortunatelly.

Comment: I think you can use `QtCore.QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath('plugins')`and it is duplicate even if this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, The problem is solved by doing two things.

1. creating/moving qt.conf file in folder where we have python.exe
2. putting following items in the `qt.conf` file

```
[Paths] 
Prefix = C:/Python27_64/Library 
Binaries = C:/Python27_64/Library/bin 
Libraries = C:/Python27_64/Library/lib 
Headers = C:/Python27_64/Library/include/qt 
Plugins = C:/Python27_64/Library/plugins
```

3. Make sure following paths are accessible.

If there is already qt.conf file available, then move it to directory where the you have `python.exe` file. Then append following at the end.
`Plugins = C:/Python27_64/Library/plugins`